# How to select GNOME at the login screen with command line

Tags: gnome-shell, login-screen, ubuntu-gnome

Is that possible to select gnome environment with command line?

The problem is when I try to select gnome in the login screen, my machine freeze and I need to restart it.

Since I can not reinstall the OS (Ubuntu 16.04) and need some Gnome Extensions, what can I do more?

Or can I put it as default, so I don't need to select it!

Login Screen Image
[image: login screen Image]

and the Freezed Login
[image: freezed login]

Comment: This could be a graphics driver issue. Or try reinstalling lightdm

Comment: No, I reinstalled ligtdm and graphic driver many times

Comment: @JasSh is your OS 16.04?? Did you install gnome session? GNOME is wayland i guess.. are you trying to access GNOME or GNOME on Xorg? regular Unity session is accessible?

Comment: @PRATAP Yes, I am using 16.04 ! I installed Gnome-shell 3.20 ! and yes, I try access GNOME ! and I am not really sure about accessing Unity session!

Comment: as kulfy mentioned it could be graphics driver issue if  you are not able to log on to default unity session. if you are sure that only by clicking the icon to select DE then the system is hanging.. try to install gdm3 and uninstall lightdm..

Comment: @PRATAP, I finally end with ask them to reinstall the OS again and the problem solved.